# Data Store - dash_table conditional formatting failing

Tags: datatable, plotly-dash, conditional-formatting, datastore

```
@dashapp.callback(
        Output(component_id='data-storage', component_property='data'),
        Input(component_id='input', component_property='n_submit')

.
.
.
   return json_data


@dashapp.callback(
        Output('table', component_property='columns'),
         Output('table', component_property='data'),
         Output('table', component_property='style_cell_conditional'),
        Input(component_id='data-storage', component_property='data'),

.
.
.

        column_name = 'Target Column'
        value = 'This value is a string'

        table_columns = [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns]
        table_data = df.to_dict("records")
        
        conditional_formatting = [{
            'if': {
                'filter_query': f'{{{column_name}}} = {value}'
                },
            'backgroundColor': 'white',
            'color'          : 'black',
            }
            ]

   return table_columns, table_data, conditional_formatting
```

1. When the code above is used **WITH the conditional_formatting** part - it works for some 'value's, and does not work for other 'value's
2. When the code above is used **WITHOUT the conditional_formatting** part - it works as expected for all 'value's

To be noted that when the conditional_formatting part is used, all callbacks are triggered twice. After this happens, the Data Store acts as if it has been infected by the "sick" value and does not allow new data.

**Example:**

**Step 1.** Use working input -> All callbacks triggered once -> Data Store is populated -> Data is displayed as expected

**Step 2.** Use working input -> All callbacks triggered once -> Data Store is populated -> Data is displayed as expected

**Step 3.** Use not working input -> All callbacks triggered once -> All callbacks are triggered again -> Data related to Input from b) is displayed

**Step 4.** Use working input -> All callbacks triggered once -> All callbacks are triggered again -> Data related to Input from b) is displayed

**Any ideas why does this happen?**

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
conditional_formatting = [{
        'if': {
            'filter_query': f'{{{column_name}}} = "{value}"'
            },
        'backgroundColor': 'white',
        'color'          : 'black',
        }
        ]
```

Issue was because the failing values had empty space (e.g. San Francisco). Adding quotes around solved the issue.